# Join items in python list separated by delimiter

Tags: python, list, delimiter

I have a list like the following

```
list_1 = ['>name', 'aaa', 'bbb', '>name_1', 'ccc', '>name_2', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff']
```

I was trying to join the items between the items with the '>" sign. So what I want is:

```
list_1 = ['>name', 'aaabbb', '>name_1', 'ccc', '>name_2', 'dddeeefff']
```

How can I do that in python?

Answer (score 5):

Use a generator function; that lets you control when items are 'done' to yield:

```
def join_unescaped(it):
    tojoin = []
    for element in it:
        if element.startswith('>'):
            if tojoin:
                yield ''.join(tojoin)
                tojoin = []
            yield element
        else:
            tojoin.append(element)
    if tojoin:
        yield ''.join(tojoin)
```

To produce a new list then from your input, pass the generator object produced to the `list()` function:

```
result = list(join_unescaped(list_1))
```

Demo:

```
>>> list_1 = ['>name', 'aaa', 'bbb', '>name_1', 'ccc', '>name_2', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff']
>>> def join_unescaped(it):
...     tojoin = []
...     for element in it:
...         if element.startswith('>'):
...             if tojoin:
...                 yield ''.join(tojoin)
...                 tojoin = []
...             yield element
...         else:
...             tojoin.append(element)
...     if tojoin:
...         yield ''.join(tojoin)
... 
>>> list(join_unescaped(list_1))
['>name', 'aaabbb', '>name_1', 'ccc', '>name_2', 'dddeeefff']
```

Comment: I would have used `str.startswith`, I guess.

Comment: @thefourtheye: for a 1 character test, I find it easier to use a 1 character slice. I'll update as it may just be clearer.

Comment: @thefourtheye: the slice is faster (no method call so no attribute lookup, etc. required) and for a fixed length test is just as easy. `str.startswith()` starts to shine when the input to the method is dynamic or a tuple.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The slice acts as if it calls `__getitem__` which is required to act as if it were an attribute lookup and method call. Plus, the slice involves a comparison operator, which is a few extra bytecodes and a call to `__eq__`. The fact that both attribute lookups and function calls here are done at the C level makes a difference, but I think it's actually the internals of `unicode_eq` vs. `unicode_startswith` that makes the biggest difference here. (And of course that's all CPython-specific…) At any rate, you're talking about (on my machine) 78ns vs. 101ns, so… who cares?

Comment: @abarnert yeah, it is a micro-optimization here.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> list_1 = ['>name', 'aaa', 'bbb', '>name_1', 'ccc', '>name_2', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff']
>>> [''.join(v) for k, v in groupby(list_1, key=lambda s: s.startswith('>'))]
['>name', 'aaabbb', '>name_1', 'ccc', '>name_2', 'dddeeefff']
```

The only case to watch for here is if you have no items between `>` signs, which requires a simple fix.

```
>>> list_1 = ['>name', '>name0', 'aaa', 'bbb', '>name_1', 'ccc', '>name_2', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff']
>>> [''.join(v) for k,v in groupby(list_1,key=lambda s:s.startswith('>')and s)]
['>name', '>name0', 'aaabbb', '>name_1', 'ccc', '>name_2', 'dddeeefff']
```

<sup>Sub note: just in the extremely unlikely case that you can have duplicate  `>name`s like `['>name', '>name', 'aaa'....]` just change `and s` to `and object()`(which is unique)  and that handles every possible case</sup>